# How to write the modified exif in source image file (like JPEG, TIFF, PSD)?

Tags: jpeg, exif, libjpeg, libexif, libjpeg-turbo

I used libexif to read and modify the exif metadata in JPEG file. I am not sure on how to write/save the modified contents in the original source image file?

Any ideas??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For JPEG you can use [`libjpeg`](https://github.com/libexif/exif/tree/master/libjpeg) from `libexif/exif` repo.